# How to use Kurento Media Server from native app?

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, kurento, peerjs

I am planning to use Kurento Media Server to record WebRtc media stream at server side.
The clients are Android and iOS and I want to develop native application for them.
In this case, can I use Peerjs or other WebRtc framework to develop the client app and connect to KMS?
If yes, how do I access KMS from the native app?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this it's late but will be useful for someone in the future. Please check this Android code to learn Android KMS integration https://github.com/MaxMaes/WebRTCTest and this other to learn how to launch the KMS server http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-recorder.html